# Custom Select with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database records sample as below

[image: Database Records]

I am getting results as below

```
SELECT
    Category, 
    SubCategory,
    COUNT(Category) AS [CategoryCount],
    CASE 
        WHEN Category = 'Vegetables' THEN 3.1
        WHEN Category = 'Animals' THEN 4.1
        WHEN Category = 'Cars' THEN 3.1
        WHEN Category = 'Fruits' THEN 2.7
    ELSE 0  END AS [OrderRank]
FROM 
    Table1
GROUP BY 
    Category
ORDER BY
    OrderRank DESC,
    Category
```

[image: SQL Results]

I would like to get results as below, I mean if grouped Category and SubCatgory rows records more than 1 Category row must be "Category" but grouped Category and SubCategory equal 1 "SubCategory" row must be blank or NULL

[image]

Comment: Can you please fix your query to match your source table and the desired result?

Comment: @PM77-1 Okay thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: Do not see any changes. Have you actually submitted your edit?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, I edited, where is the problem?

Comment: You do not have `Country` field in your table but use it in `WHEN` condition.  You are missing a comma. You check for `Animals` twice.  You need `SUM` (not `COUNT`)  to get the desired result.

Comment: @PM77-1 I am sorry I have fixed again. But I am getting CategoryCount with COUNT function in the real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Category, 
    CASE 
       WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategory) > 1 THEN ''
       ELSE MAX(SubCategory)
    END,
    COUNT(Category) AS [CategoryCount],
    CASE 
        WHEN Category = 'Vegetables' THEN 5.3
        WHEN Category = 'Animals' THEN 4.1
        WHEN Category = 'Cars' THEN 3.1
        WHEN Category = 'Fruits' THEN 2.7
    ELSE 0  END AS [OrderRank]
FROM 
    Table1
GROUP BY 
    Category
ORDER BY
    OrderRank DESC,
    Category
```

Give this a shot.

Using a case statement to check your count you can either supply the subCategory or blank.

EDIT: Answer change after Kerebos updated question.

Running the code I have posted above generates the following result set:

[image]

I have updated the COUNT() case statement to check for distinct subcategories. It isn't the prettiest solution but it works

Besides the fact your Orderrank is different (which is because you have run code that is different to what you have posted because they are hard coded values) the code generates the expected result set. If the ordering is the issue then just change the ordering.

EDIT2: I've just updated my code to generate the correct ordering as per your question.

Comment: I am sorry my question was wrong because of me. Your codes is not working for me ror this reason. I edited my question. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

for having the result that you want, based on the @jamesLuxton answer you just need to change this line.

```
  COUNT(Category) AS [CategoryCount],
```

for this one

```
  SUM(Categorycount) AS [CategoryCount],
```

final SQL will be this one

```
SELECT
   Category, 
    CASE 
   WHEN COUNT(Category) > 1 THEN ''
   ELSE MAX(SubCategory)
END,
sum(Categorycount) AS [CategoryCount],
CASE 
    WHEN Category = 'Vegetables' THEN 3.1
    WHEN Category = 'Animals' THEN 4.1
    WHEN Category = 'Cars' THEN 3.1
    WHEN Category = 'Fruits' THEN 2.7
ELSE 0  END AS [OrderRank] FROM 
Table1 GROUP BY 
Category
 ORDER BY
      OrderRank DESC,
Category
```

hope this help.

Good Answer by @james

Comment: I am sorry my question was wrong because of me. Your codes is not working for me ror this reason. I edited my question. Sorry again.